# Error in reading an sql file using pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have an sql file locally stored in my PC. I want to open and read it using the pandas library. Here it iswhat I have tried:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import sqlite3

 my_file = 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\\database.sql'
 #I am creating an empty database
 conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\test\Downloads\test.db')
 #I am reading my file 
 df = pd.read_sql(my_file, conn)
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\database.sql': near "C": syntax error

Comment: try `my_file = r'C:\Users\me\Downloads\\database.sql'` so you pass a raw string, or use forward slashes

Comment: @EdChum Didn't work :(

Comment: remove the double \\ and change to a single \ in the .sql path, with the raw string encoding as what EdChum said earlier

Comment: how about `my_file = 'C://Users/me/Downloads/database.sql'`

Comment: To elaborate on @EdChum's comment, Python will try to convert everything after `'\U'` in `'C:\Users'` to unicode which will break the "path string". Definitely use `r` to signify it's a raw string. Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences

Comment: I tried your suggestions but still no result. I am wondering if the nature of the problem is the encoding of the string or something in the process.

Comment: I also change the directory to a folder containing all the data and the script in order not use forward/backslash but I am receiving the same error tho.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the file to D://
Sometimes Python is not granted access to read/write in C. 
Hence may be that is an issue.

You can also try alternative method using cursors.

cur=conn.cursor()

r=cur.fetchall()

This r would contain a tuple of your dataset.